# QGIS style "- x x -"

Tags: style

Please suggest how to draw a style like **- x x -** (dash cross cross dash), with a dash length 25 mm and gap between dash and cross is 2mm

Answer (score 5):

It's possible only in QGIS 2.3 and above (so will be possible in the upcoming 2.4 stable release). Here's how (I'm assuming here you want a gap of 2mm between the two crosses and between the two dashes also):

- Add a simple line symbol layer, set the cap style to flat, tick "Use custom dash pattern" then click "Change" and copy the settings values below:

[image]

- Add another symbol layer, change it to a "marker line" symbol layer type. Tick "with interval" and enter 13.00 (make sure it's set to millimeters). Set the "offset along line" to 4.5:

[image]

- Expand out the tree below this marker line till you get to the "simple marker" item, click it and choose a cross style symbol
- Add another symbol layer, change it again to a marker line with an interval of 13.00. This time set the "offset along line" to 6.5 mm. Again, change it's marker type to a cross symbol:

[image]

And you're done!..

[image]